# Web Setup Wizard gives 401 after upgrade

Tags: magento2, upgrade, web-setup-wizard

I had a Magento 2.0.2 and upgraded into 2.0.4 version through Web Setup Wizard.
Everything worked fine,  and the frontend and backend work properly, but when I'm trying to access the Web Setup Wizard from the back-end, I get an error:

"Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters. 
To use the Magento setup wizard sign into your Admin account and navigate to System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard"

Can someone please help me fix this.
Thanks

-Armindo

Comment: That message displays if you go to the `/setup` URI I believe. Try clearing the cache and the `var/generation` directory, log out from Admin, log back in.

Comment: I've tried that, but still get the same message. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any solution for this error. I am facing the same trouble after successful installation even after reinstalling the same error occurs.

Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters. 
To use the Magento setup wizard sign into your Admin account and navigate to System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

- Base URLs (Secure)
  -> Use Secure URLs on Storefront -> Yes

  -> Use Secure URLs in Admin -> Yes

  -> Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) -> Yes

  -> Upgrade Insecure Requests -> Yes

php bin/magento cache:clean

https://yadi.sk/i/iPJi4k7X3S86Za

Comment: trying it but not getting soution  same error http://prntscr.com/jof867

Comment: Check file/folder permissions from host / reset it. Also, can check on other hosting if can do this or local host.